# ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am trying to run below file
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

When trying to run below command,I am getting error
pip install .
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

My current location is /content/models/research.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the CP line below based on an article about [Installing Tensorflow Object Detection](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/installing-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api) and it resolved this issue. Basically it copies setup.py so pip can find it.

```
%%bash 
cd models/research
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
pip install . --upgrade
```

Comment: Thank You @husky58.This is the correct solution. This has worked for me as well.